android.graphics.Path in Compose
I try place image behind cutout. And by documentation I can get path of cutout (LocalView.current.view.rootWindowInsets.displayCutout.cutout.cutoutPath)
But this path is android.graphics.Path and compose Canvas get androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path for draw. I don't find any information about mapping android.graphics.Path to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path or drawing android.graphics.Path in Compose.
Does anyone know how I can use android.graphics.Path in Compose?

Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of the answer.

You can convert android.graphics.Path to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path  with path.asComposePath(). Inside Canvas' or Modifier.drawWithContent/Behind/drawWithCache which both have lambdas for DrawScope for drawing, you can draw path.
val path: Path = Path()
val composePath: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path = path.asComposePath()


Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    // Like this
    drawPath(composePath, Color.Red)
    // or like this
    drawPath(path.asComposePath(), Color.Red)
}


Thank you, I don't know how I missed it
